# Python how to join inner arrays and conctenate key values

Tags: python, json

I have json file:

```
 [ 
 {
 "query": {
 "key1": "value1",
 "key2": "value2"
 }
 }
 ]
```

Need to join this array with one line so output will be:

```
key1=value1&key2=value2
```

I can get key value string with:

```
import json

with open('task.json', 'r') as f:
    json_dict = json.load(f)
for key, value in json_dict.iteritems():
    print("{}={}".format(key, value))
```

```
key2=value2
key1=value1
```

But how to join and sort all elements of array to get this:

```
key1=value1&key2=value2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following input:

```
[
   {
      "query":{
         "key2":"value2",
         "key1":"value1"
      }
   }
]
```

Try this code:

```
import json
from urllib.parse import urlencode

with open('task.json', 'r') as f:
    json_dict = json.load(f)
    sorted_dict = dict(sorted(json_dict[0]['query'].items()))
    urlencode(sorted_dict)
```

and gives:

```
#output: 'key1=value1&key2=value2'
```

#### Brief explanation

1. Read the json file in a python dictionary
2. Filter and sort (by key) the dictionary in ascending order
3. Format the result using [urlib.parse.urlencode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode)

Answer (score 0):

Here, I had to go through two lists to be sure you get the desired result. First create a list with two tuples, each represeting a `key1,=,value1` set, then turn that into two string values in, to be latter joined and printed as full string `key1=value1&key2=value2`. The good thing about this script, is that you should be able to add as many key,value pairs within json_file[0]['query'] without making this code fail.

```
json_file = [{"query": {"key1": "value1","key2": "value2"}}]
a = []
b = []
for i in json_file[0]['query']:
    a.append((i,'=',json_file[0]['query'][i]))
for i in a:
    b.append(''.join(i))
print('&'.join(b))
```

Output:

```
key1=value1&key2=value2
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `urllib`:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
urlencode(some_dictionary)
```

A test:

```
>>> s = {
...  "key1": "value1",
...  "key2": "value2"
...  }
>>> urlencode(s)
'key1=value1&key2=value2'
```